# Cordova - Security using client-side Facebook Oauth

Tags: cordova, laravel-5, ionic-framework, facebook-oauth

I am currently making an Ionic Cordova application, which needs Facebook Auth.
I am using Nic Raboy's very simple [plugin](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-facebook-example) for this. I've made a diagram to show how the current flow is.
[image]

The question is: If in some weird way, an adversary, knows the path for registration on my (Laravel 5.1) server; can't they just [get the Facebook ID](http://findmyfbid.com/) and just make up a fake access token + additional data, and create a user on behalf of someone else?

Even if this hypothetically isn't an issue, how do I assure that a user logging in is the actual user logging in? Since the registration/logging in is the same using Facebook as authentication, I assume the server is checking up on some value. It would make sense for me to use the Facebook Access Token, but since that token often changes, it doesn't seem reliable to me.

I also had a look at Laravel's Socialite, but it seems that it only works with views, which I obviously can't, since I am using the server as a REST-server.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would have your server talking directly to FB. The accepted approach would be:

1. Cordova application performs handshake and gets the *FacebookID*, an *Access Token*, and other credentials from the Facebook App.
2. The Cordova application send this info to your server.
3. **Important:** The server uses those credentials and talk directly to FB. In this way the server performs the validation typically by using the *Access Token* to talk with FB. Using the *Access Token* it gets the info from FB an makes sure that everything matches up. For example it would check that the *FacebookID* sent from Cordova app is the same as the *FacebookID* retrieved  directly from FB.

More info on this approach can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow). The link attached specifically states:

```
The call will need to be server-to-server, since it involves your app secret.
```

This approach usually assures no third party attacks. Even if someone knows your facebook id (which they can easily get since it's public) they cannot pretend to be you because they lack the access token (which expires).

Comment: Knew I was missing something like this. 
Thanks a lot. I'll try it out today, and accept your answer if it works. 
If not, i'll just cry some more.

Comment: Just a little extra info if you like. I have managed to achieve the desired flow by using [this](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) Cordova plugin and [this](http://restfb.com/) backend library.